# How to dispose SmppServer correctly?

Tags: c#, inetlab.smpp

I use [Inetlab.SMPP Library](https://docs.inetlab.com/smpp/index.html) to implement a RE (Routing Entity in SMPP 5.0 terms). I have some questions about [`Stop()`](https://docs.inetlab.com/smpp/v2.8/api/Inetlab.SMPP.SmppServer.Stop.html) and [`Dispose()`](https://docs.inetlab.com/smpp/v2.8/api/Inetlab.SMPP.SmppServer.Dispose.html#Inetlab_SMPP_SmppServer_Dispose) methods of an [`SmppServer`](https://docs.inetlab.com/smpp/v2.8/api/Inetlab.SMPP.SmppServer.html) instance:

1. Is it necessary to call the [`Stop()`](https://docs.inetlab.com/smpp/v2.8/api/Inetlab.SMPP.SmppServer.Stop.html) method before disposing [`SmppServer`](https://docs.inetlab.com/smpp/v2.8/api/Inetlab.SMPP.SmppServer.html) instance?
2. Does the [`Stop()`](https://docs.inetlab.com/smpp/v2.8/api/Inetlab.SMPP.SmppServer.Stop.html) method throw an exception if [`SmppServer`](https://docs.inetlab.com/smpp/v2.8/api/Inetlab.SMPP.SmppServer.html) instance is already stopped?
3. May the methods throw an exception?

So, is the following snippet correct?

```cs
class MyService : IHostedService, IDisposable
{
    private readonly SmppServer _server = null;

    public MyService()
    {
        _server = new SmppServer()
        {
            // configure SMPP server here
        };
    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _server.Start(cancellationToken);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _server.Stop();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _server?.Stop();
        _server?.Dispose();
    }

    // implement logic here
}
```

Do I need to use `try...catch` block within the `Dispose()` method? Is it possible to exclude `_server?.Stop()` line?

Comment: You could likely answer the second question easily enough by trial-and-error. As Unfortunately, since [the documentation for `SmppServer`](https://docs.inetlab.com/smpp/v2.9/api/Inetlab.SMPP.SmppServer.html) doesn't list the exceptions that can be thrown, nor do they offer their source code, it's going to be challenging to answer the third question comprehensively. (You could try decompiling the library to look for explicit throw statements, but that's not going to identify exceptions thrown by the CLR based on their logic.) Based on that, it may be worth taking this up with the vendor.

Comment: As an aside, [the documentation](https://docs.inetlab.com/smpp/v2.9/api/Inetlab.SMPP.SmppServer.Stop.html) _does_ note that the `Stop()` method is now obsolete, in favor of `StopAsync()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Is it necessary to call the Stop() method before disposing SmppServer instance?

No, you don't need to call Stop method before Dispose. Dispose method as well as Stop method closes all active connections and stops the SmppServer.

> 2. Does the Stop() method throw an exception if SmppServer instance is already stopped?

Stop method does nothing when SmppServer is already stopped.

I would change the snippet to

```cs
class MyService : IHostedService, IDisposable
{
    private readonly SmppServer _server;

    public MyService()
    {
        _server = new SmppServer()
        {
            // configure SMPP server here
        };
    }

   public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return _server.StartAsync(cancellationToken);
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return _server.StopAsync(cancellationToken);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _server.Dispose();
    }

    // implement logic here
}
```